# Oracle PLSQL using a dynamic variable in a where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, where-clause

For testing in Toad, I have the following code

```
select ...
from ...
where term_code = :termcode AND
        (
          case 
           when :theSubject is not null then SUBJ_CODE = :theSubject
           else 1 = 1
          end
        )          
AND ptrm_code <> 8
```

In short: If theSubject is not entered (is null) I want to display all the courses, otherwise I want to display only those where subject_code is the same as the one entered in the variable window in Toad.

But I get an error:
[Error] Execution (77: 68): ORA-00905: missing keyword
in here:
*when :theCourse is not null then sect.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE = theCourse*

Comment: A [case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html) lets you have a value or expression as the `then` or `else` result; not a condition, which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: The statement you show mentions `:theSubject` but the error message mentions `:theCourse`; thus it seems that the error message does not refer to the statement shown. Also, in the error message the second occurrence of `theCourse` is not preceded by a colon. ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use boolean logic:

```
where 
    term_code = :termcode 
    and (:theSubject is null or subj_code = :theSubject)
```